# Arithmetic theorems explainable to a high schooler using $\infty$-category theory in a crucial way

Tags: ct.category-theory

For some context, Fermat's last theorem has a beautiful statement, which can be explained to a high schooler, it appears naturally when teaching the pythagorean theorem and just a bit of generalization gets you all the way to its statement. Its proof uses connections between various parts of modern mathematics.

What about a theorem that goes even further, its statement is arithmetic, can be naturally motivated at a high school level and its proof goes into the realm of $\infty$-categories.
Are there such statements? Maybe the answer is much simpler and the statement is Fermat's last theorem as I am not an expert.

For context, my experience with category theory comes from formal verification of software and modularity issues therein. While one might argue this can be motivated to a high schooler, the issues come in at a different scale. I would argue that these issues would show up in a well-designed computer science class for high schoolers, but that the objects in any concrete theorems directly depending on them will be much harder to motivate at this level without a course in rigorous formal logic or some amount of software engineering practice. Compared to these, in Fermat's last theorem all the objects and operations in the statement come without going beyond the standard curriculum.

Comment: I removed my upvote after the most recent edit; I think it is a big but reasonable ask for a theorem explainable to high schoolers that uses category theory in an essential way, but asking for $\infty$-categories to be used is absurd imo.

Comment: That's a good point, I have realized that i was talking about ∞/(∞,n)-categories in the question, so I decided to just update the title. But it might be better to update the question itself.

Comment: @AlecRhea I don't think this is absurd. Just asking for category theory is a trivial question - Fermat is already an example of this unless you want to be absurdly stringent about "essential". For infinity-categories, I don't think there exists an example now but probably there will be in 50 years.

Comment: I have somewhat quickly skimmed over the proof of Fermat's last theorem before and right now I have double checked for categories and functors to appear, so I am deciding to be consistent on infinity categories. Note that, if I cared about "essential", I could argue for just adding axioms to peanno arithmetic.

Comment: I'd say that $(\infty, n)$-category theory is still pretty young, and you shouldn't expect it as of today to solve problems explainable to high-school students that are beyond the reach of old established fields like algebraic number theory and algebraic geometry. Let's be clear not to mythologize higher category theory as blowing other powerful fields out of the water, at least not yet.

Comment: Infinity categories show up in Gaitsgory and Lurie's proof that the Tamagawa number of a simply connected simple algebraic group over a function field over a finite field is equal to 1. This is still quite far from a statement that you could explain to a high schooler, but for all I know it could imply something nontrivial about some elementary diophantine equation. It's sort of an accident that Fermat's last theorem is connected to elliptic curves and modular forms, and if there's an answer to your question then it's probably also an accident of that sort.

Comment: @ToddTrimble I am quite new to it and was curious whether there are results of that form. I am trying to find interesting examples, which seem elementary, fermat's last theorem being an example and informed comments of this form was what I was looking for in the negative case, as this could have gone in either direction.

Comment: @WillSawin Yes, I didn’t mean that there will never be such an example, just not one currently that uses infinity categories ‘essentially’ since they only crop up in very abstract areas at the moment. But after a more careful reading of the question I see that this may not be relevant; user4242, are you just asking for easily stated arithmetic theorems that can be proven using higher category theory?

Comment: @AlecRhea that's correct, theorem that's easily stated as a teaser for motivated students. I found that motivations for various fields, i.e. insolubility of quintics -> galois theory, which was used to play around with groups as an abstraction, helped me with motivation to go further into maths. So in this case it is look we can take processes of generalization very far, it leads to interesting results. Showing the process of generalization by looking at adding arrows between arrows and saying we can keep doing this and it will lead to something we can already talk about. But now I am unsure.